# Saving Results of Access Query To Worksheet Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I cant seem to find an easy way of doing outside of just accessing the SQL from ACCESS SQL View and doing it manually. Is there some magic way to use this code below and do that?

Its worth pointing out that I am trying to do this from Excel's VBA.

```
Private Sub tryagain()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection

    With con
     .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
     .Open "C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop" & "\" & "xyzmanu3.accdb"
    End With

    con.Execute "Invoice Query"

    'How do output to Worksheet?

    rs.Close
    cmd.ActiveConnection.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: @ScottCraner I know youre the super duper excel bad ass here.... <3

Comment: Start with this example and then come back with any problems (and code) that you have https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246335

Comment: I already know how to do ad hoc queries using excel vba into/pulling from access, I am trying to figure out how to treat saved queries like stored procedures (and calling them from excel vba) and them output the content into excel. Also the link you posted is for Acces-VBA where as my tags include Excel-VBA. I will update my description to make it more obvious.

Comment: Use the `Access-VBA` code, it will work unless you have all references.

Comment: Well its nice to have but it isnt what im trying to do. I have been playing around with the link though :)

Comment: Where is the mismatch (copies query `Select * From Orders` result to sheet1). You can use a query name too.

Comment: Don't forget to use @Bit in comment  to get me notified! http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the ADO recordset object which you initialize, call the query, and then run the [Range.CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx) method (specifying the leftmost worksheet cell to place results).

Also, see the changed connection open routine with proper connection string. And because recordsets do not pull in column headers automatically but only data, an added loop was included iterating through recordset's field names.

```
Private Sub tryagain()
    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim i as Integer, fld As Object

    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop\xyzmanu3.accdb';"

    con.Open strConnection    
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Invoice Query]", con

   ' column headers
    i = 0
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Activate
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = fld.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next fld

    ' data rows
    Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    cn.Close  
End Sub
```

By the way, this same above setup can even query Excel workbooks as the Jet/ACE SQL Engine is a Windows technology (.dll files) available to all Office or Windows programs.

```
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                   & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
                   & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
```